# How can I search a directory recursively for any if statements with only one statement in them?

Tags: bash, grep

E.g:

```
if ($bar) {
    $foo = 1;
}
```

I've been trying with regular expressions and newlines in grep but my conclusion is that grep is only capable of looking at one line at a time, so what tool do I need to use to search these out?

Thanks

Comment: I would think `sed` locating `if` and then searching between the pattern `[{]` and `[}]`. `sed` also provides the `n` and `N` command to  read/append the next line to pattern space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\s*if\s*(.*)/{N;/\s*{$/N; N;/}\s*$/p}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
if ($bar) {
    $foo = 1;
}

if ($bar) {
    $foo = 1;
    $foo = 2;
}

if ($foo)
{
    $foo = 1;
}
if ($foo)
{
    $foo = 1;
    $foo = 2;
}

$ sed -n '/^\s*if\s*(.*)/{N;/\s*{$/N; N;/}\s*$/p}' file
if ($bar) {
    $foo = 1;
}
if ($foo)
{
    $foo = 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  And once I have that starting point trivial to adapt it to other scenarios (if/else, etc)